# Parsing XML with Perl

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

Total noob here so I am sorry for my ignorance in advance.

Most of what I have searched and messed around with has centered around using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) with XPath.

The problem that I have is that I am not looking to capture text between tags: I need values of the tags.

This is my XML structure

```
<users>
  <entry name="asd">
    <permissions>
      <role-based>
        <superuser>yes</superuser>
      </role-based>
    </permissions>
  </entry>
  <entry name="fgh">
    <permissions>
      <role-based>
        <superuser>yes</superuser>
      </role-based>
    </permissions>
    <authentication-profile>RSA Two-Factor</authentication-profile>
  </entry>
  <entry name="jkl">
    <permissions>
      <role-based>
        <superreader>yes</superreader>
      </role-based>
    </permissions>
    <authentication-profile>RSA Two-Factor</authentication-profile>
  </entry>
</users>
```

I am trying to grab the name attribute (without the quotes) and also determine whether this person is a superuser or superreader.

I am stuck at not being able to do much other than print off the nodes. I need to turn this into a CSV file in the structure of username; role

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to extract information from XML documents with `XML::LibXML` is to use the `find` family of methods. These methods use an XPath expression to select nodes and values from the document. The following script extracts the data you need:

```perl
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'so.xml');

for my $entry ($doc->findnodes('//entry')) {
    my $name = $entry->getAttribute('name');
    my $role = $entry->findvalue(
        'local-name(permissions/role-based/*[.="yes"])'
    );
    print("$name;$role\n");
}
```

It prints

```
asd;superuser
fgh;superuser
jkl;superreader
```

I used the `local-name` XPath function to get the name of the role element.

Note that you might want to use `Text::CSV` to create CSV files in a more robust way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I will have to try this out.  When I was attempting to use the getAttribute call before it was telling me that it was unknown in my package.  I was using XML:LibXML, maybe I have dependency issues somewhere?

Comment: @user2891632, if you're still having problems, post a new question showing the actual code you're using and the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with a different module, `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my ($name, $role);

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'entry' => sub { 
            $name = $_->att('name');
            if ( defined $name && defined $role ) { 
                printf qq|%s;%s\n|, $name, $role;
            }   
            map { undef $_ } ($name, $role);
        },  
        'role-based' => sub { $role = $_->first_child->tag },
    },  
)->parsefile( shift );
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
asd;superuser
fgh;superuser
jkl;superreader
```

Answer (score 2):

Using XML::Rules:

```
use XML::Rules;

print "name is_superuser is_superreader\n";
my @rules = (
  entry => sub {
    my $entry = $_[1];
    $_ ||= 'no' for @$entry{qw(superuser superreader)};
    print "$entry->{name} $entry->{superuser} $entry->{superreader}\n";
  },
  'permissions,role-based' => 'pass no content',
  'superuser,superreader' => 'content',
  _default => undef,
);

my $p = XML::Rules->new(rules => \@rules);
my $s = $p->parse(doc());

sub doc {
return <<XML;
<users>
   <entry name="asd">
       <permissions>
            <role-based>
                <superuser>yes</superuser>
            </role-based>
       </permissions>
   </entry>
   <entry name="fgh">
       <permissions>
            <role-based>
                <superuser>yes</superuser>
            </role-based>
       </permissions>
       <authentication-profile>RSA Two-Factor</authentication-profile>
   </entry>
   <entry name="jkl">
       <permissions>
            <role-based>
                <superreader>yes</superreader>
            </role-based>
       </permissions>
       <authentication-profile>RSA Two-Factor</authentication-profile>
   </entry>
</users>
XML
}
```

Or an optional set of rules assuming all content is 'yes' (and some other assumptions) for your key fields:

```
my $name;
my @rules = (
  '^entry' => sub {
    $name = $_[1]->{name};
  },
  'superuser,superreader' => sub {
    print "$name,$_[0]\n";
  },
  _default => undef,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using `XML::Simple` for projects like this.

For example:

```
use XML::Simple;

my $su = $ARGV[0];
die unless (-e $su);

my $su_xml = XMLin($su, ForceArray => [ 'entry' ]);
my $suref = $su_xml->{entry};

foreach my $key (keys %{$suref}) {
    $rb = ${$suref}{$key}->{permissions}->{'role-based'};
    foreach my $rbkey (keys %{$rb}) {
        print "$key\t$rbkey\t${$rb}{$rbkey}\n";
    }
}
```

prints:

```
fgh     superuser       yes
asd     superuser       yes
jkl     superreader     yes
```

Comment: `XML::Simple` is often too simple. For example, your script breaks if there's only one `<entry>` within `<users>`.

Comment: @SlavenRezic Good catch!  Fortunately, `XML::Simple` is highly configurable and easily accounts for this case through the use of `ForceArray`.  Solution updated.